# Ошибки в описании новогодних шляп

Tags: дефект, локализация, новогодние-шляпы

Заметил следующие ошибки в русских текстах шляп.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Испол**Ь**зовать. Да и "использовать чат" звучит как-то не очень.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если мы не в течении реки Волги, то писать надо "в течени**е**"

Ну и ссылка "About this hat" вероятно нуждается в переводе.

Comment: _Посидеть в беседке_ - Round 2. Fight!

Comment: Try Dark Mode почему-то так и остался на английском